# Не знаю где взять идентификатор Сonsole

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

static void Main(string[]) 

{

int monthNumber;

Console.Write("Введите номер месяца: ");

monthNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (monthNumber <= 12 && monthNumber >= 1)

{

    if ((monthNumber == 12) || (monthNumber <= 2)) Console.Write("Время года - зима");

    else if ((monthNumber >= 3) && (monthNumber <= 5)) Console.Write("Время года - весна");

    else if ((monthNumber >= 6) && (monthNumber <= 8)) Console.Write("Время года - лето");

    else if ((monthNumber >= 9) && (monthNumber <= 11)) Console.Write("Время года - осень");

}

else

{
    Console.Write("Неверный номер месяца.");

}

Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: Это C# или что?

Comment: ``#include <string>`` это с++  а вот  ``using`` это c# =) Проверьте свой код еще раз и опишите вашу проблему более подробно

Comment: Проект какого типа и на каком языке вы создали?

Comment: Судя по меткам C++ (которые зря удалили), вы вероятно пытаетесь изучать этот язык. Так вот, для этой цели вместо Visual Studio возьмите другую IDE. Потому что VS категорически не подходит для изучения C++. Именно потому, что позволяет создавать проекты на множестве разных языков. В итоге новички путаются и учат не то, что надо.

Comment: @АртурФранк `using namespace std;` это тоже C++. А `static void Main`, `Console` и `Convert` - это похоже из C#. Вообще смесь языков получилась.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно подключить основную C# библиотеку:

```
using System;
```

Обычно она по умолчанию уже подключена. `Console` находится именно в ней.